# Авторизация Retrofit 2

Tags: java, header, retrofit2

Добрый день помогите разобраться с кодом. Хочу получить данные с сервера в формате JSON. На сервере стоит авторизация. При попытки получить ответ от сервера получаю ошибку 401. Сам код

```
package com.ocean_shop.myapplication;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";
    String username = "Пользовател";
    String password = "Пароль";

    public interface MessagesApi {

        @GET("http://SERVER/ocean_shop/odata/standard.odata/AccumulationRegister_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8/Turnovers(StartPeriod=datetime'2018-02-06',%20EndPeriod=datetime'2018-02-07')?$format=json;odata=nometadata")
        Call<List<Message>> messages();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {




            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request();
                Request newRequest;

                newRequest = request.newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8")
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP))

                        .build();
                log("client " + "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP));

                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }

        });





        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://SERVER/ocean_shop/odata/standard.odata/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        MessagesApi messagesApi = retrofit.create(MessagesApi.class);


        Call<List<Message>> messages = messagesApi.messages();

        messages.enqueue(new Callback<List<Message>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Message>> call, Response<List<Message>> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    log("response " + response.body().size());
                } else {

                    log("response headers " + response.headers());
                    log("response code " + response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Message>> call, Throwable t) {
                log("failure " + t);
            }
        });

    }

    private void log(String s) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, s);
    }

}
```

Logcat

```
02-12 11:28:48.558 11080-11080/com.ocean_shop.myapplication D/my_log: response headers Cache-Control: private
                                                                      Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
                                                                      Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
                                                                      WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="1C:Enterprise 8.3"
                                                                      Date: Mon, 12 Feb 2018 11:28:48 GMT
                                                                      Content-Length: 6954
02-12 11:28:48.558 11080-11080/com.ocean_shop.myapplication D/my_log: response code 401
```

Answer (score 1):

Код полностью рабочий. Авторизация не должно содержать кириллицу. Собственно в этом и была ошибка.